# Increasing a value every 5 seconds

Tags: c++

I'm making a simple meteor and rocket game in the console. And I want to increase the spawnrate of the meteors every five seconds. I have already tried the Sleep() function but that will of course not work and sleep the whole application. So does a while loop.

I will only post the Logic() function where it must increase because it's a program
of like 100 lines and I didn't feel like posting it all in here. If you do need context just ask me and I will post everything.

```
void Logic() {
        Sleep(5000); // TODO Increase meteors every Five seconds
        nMeteors++;
}
```

I'm pretty stuck on this so it would be nice if someone could help me :)

Comment: This really depends on the platform environment. For example, are threads allowed? Can you use Windows timers?

Comment: You could also use a timestamp. If 5 seconds have elapsed since previous time, update value.

Comment: The C++ standard library have very good [time and duration facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). You can use them for timing in your main event loop.

Comment: You could use some kind of ticker. Your game will have "ticks", and on each tick, certain actions happen. There could be 5 ticks a second, for instance. On every 5th tick you run certain logic, including the logic that will increase the spawnrate. This ticking system is used by an MMORPG I play, works pretty well there.

Comment: 100 lines is a **tiny** program. You still can reduce this to fewer lines by only including the parts where you deal wuth simultaneous keyboard input and console output (*what* gets output is unimportant so you can omit all of that).

Comment: Thank you for the Link Some programmer dude. I'll look into it. I'm not so familliar to C++ because I just started doing it, so it takes a little longer to respond to everyone. Because I have to lookup all the terms you guys are saying haha :). I'm still mostly working with standart library stuff.

Comment: Unrelated: Standard Library input routines are not good for video games because they block. Say you want know what direction the player wants to go in. You can't `cin >>direction;` because the program will stop and wait for the user to hit some keys and then the enter button. In a game this is almost never what you want.

Comment: Yeah I know, for that I used GetAsyncKeyState(), that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly two ways to approach this problem. One would be to spawn a new thread and put the loop there. You can use C++11's standard libraries `<thread>` and `<chrono`. Putting the thread to sleep for 5 seconds is as simple as `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{5});`

But dedicating an entire thread to such a trivial task is unnecessary. In a videogame you usually have some sort of time keeping variable.

What you'd want to do is probably have a variable like `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> previous_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();` (or simply `auto previous_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`) outside of your loop. Now you have a reference point you can use to know where you are in time while running your loop. Inside of your loop you create another variable like `auto current_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();`, this is your current time. Now it's a simple matter of calculating the difference between `current_time` and `previous_time` and check if 5 seconds have passed. If they have, increase your variable and don't forget to set `previous_time = current_time;` to update the time, if not then just skip and keep doing whatever else you need to do in your main game loop.

To check if 5 seconds have passed, you do `if (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(current_time - previous_time).count() >= 5) { ... }`.

You can find a lot more info [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) for the `chrono` library and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/thread) for the `thread` library. Plus, Google is your friend.

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped me. I'll look into this and threads some more, but this really helps me spreads my knowledge about C++!

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to write a game is to have an event loop.

The event loop polls various inputs for status, updates the state of the game, and then repeats.  Some clever event loops even sleep for short periods and get notifications when inputs change or state has to be updated.

In your meteor spawning code, keep track of a timestamp when the last increase in spawnrate occurred.  When you check if a meteor should spawn or spawn meteors 5 seconds after that point, update the spawn rate and record a new timestamp (possibly retroactively, and possibly in a loop to handle more than 10 seconds passing between checks for whatever reason).

An alternative solution involving an extra thread of execution is possible, but not a good idea.

As an aside, most games want to support pausing; so you want to distinguish between wall-clock time and nominal game-play time.

Answer (score 0):

I found this easier than using chrono

Open to feedbacks:

Code:-

include "time.h"

main(){

```
int d;

time_t s,e;

time(&s);

time(&e);

d=e-s;

while(d<5){

    cout<<d;

    time(&e);

    d=e-s;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by making your value a *function of elapsed time*. For example:

```
// somewhere to store the beginning of the 
// time period.
inline std::time_t& get_start_timer()
{
    static std::time_t t{};
    return t;
}

// Start a time period (resets meteors to zero)
inline void start_timer()
{
    get_start_timer() = std::time(nullptr); // current time in seconds
}

// retrieve the current number of meteors
// as a function of time.
inline int nMeteors()
{
    return int(std::difftime(std::time(nullptr), get_start_timer())) / 5;
}

int main()
{
    start_timer();

    for(;;)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        std::cout << "meteors: " << nMeteors() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Here is a similar version using `C++11` `<chrono>` library:

```
// somewhere to store the beginning of the
// time period.
inline auto& get_time_point()
{
    static std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point tp{};
    return tp;
}

// Start a time period (resets meteors to zero)
inline void start_timing()
{
    get_time_point() = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); // current time in seconds
}

// retrieve the current number of meteors
// as a function of time.
inline auto nMeteors()
{
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - get_time_point()).count() / 5;
}

int main()
{
    start_timing();

    for(;;)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        std::cout << "meteors: " << nMeteors() << '\n';
    }
}
```